# Control flexboxes on smaller screensizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn how to work with flexboxes. I have made an example here:

```css
/* Grid */

.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .column {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
/* Style */

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #343436;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 1 - 100% 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 2 - 50%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 3 - 50%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 4 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 5 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 6 - 33.3%
  </div>
</div>
```

So the flexboxes above is working how I would like `> 800px`. Below I made an image of how I would like the grid to look, when the screensize is `< 800px`. **But I cannot figure out how I make this in CSS?**. I was hoping someone could learn me a good way to do this.

At the moment the flexboxes are just gonna take full-width on mobile, and I would like to have more control over the layout on mobile, so the layout is looking like this on `< 800px`:

[image: Flexbox on mobile]

Comment: While I appreciate you want learn how to use flex layout your comment, in the CSS, tells you that this layout should use grid layout, especially since you’re creating a two dimensional layout.

Comment: If you wanted that layout with your current html, you would need to allow your rows to wrap and the  set sizes for your columns according to your layout

Comment: In your image you mention column 4, 5, and 6 as each having 33% width but it appears to 4 and 5 have 50% width and column 6 has 100% width. Which one is correct?

Comment: @TylerH I think the OP set it up with the markup from desktop, but mobile wants that last div to be 100%.

Comment: @MK-DK I wonder why you want 1 column layout in a large device while multiple columns layout for the small one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the easiest way to do this is with CSS Grid layout I've included that later in the answer. First, though, is the flex layout.

I've amended your HTML, though, since it's far easier without the `.row()` wrapper elements. Note, also, that I've used minimum, and maximum, widths of `500px` instead of `800px`; this is simply to demonstrate more easily within a Stack Snippet and JS Fiddle demo; if you replace the widths in the demo with your own preferred widths they'll work just the same for those widths.

```css
/* For screens less than 500px in width: */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .cell1,
  .cell6 {
    /* here we want these elements to grow to a
       size twice that of their siblings, not to
       shrink at all and be 100% wide minus the
       doubled width of the margin (we use a CSS
       custom property to set the margin on the
       elements) */
    flex: 2 0 calc(100% - var(--margin) * 2);
  }
  .cell2,
  .cell3,
  .cell4,
  .cell5 {
    /* The remaining cells are all set to neither
       grow nor shrink, and their flex-basis is
       50% minus the calculated width of the
       margins in order to allow two elements
       per row: */
    flex: 1 0 calc(50% - var(--margin) * 2);
  }
}
/* for screens larger than 500px width: */
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .cell1 {
    /* This element is up to three times
       the size of its siblings, does not
       shrink in relation to them and has
       a flex-basis of 100% minus the width
       of the margins: */
    flex: 3 0 calc(100% - var(--margin) * 2);
  }
  .cell2,
  .cell3 {
    /* two elements per 'row': */
    flex: 2 0 calc(50% - var(--margin) * 2);
  }
  .cell4,
  .cell5,
  .cell6 {
    /* three elements per 'row': */
    flex: 1 0 calc(33.3% - var(--margin) * 2);
  }
}


/* to force widths to be more consistently applied
   between different element-types and browsers: */

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  /* the declaration of the --margin
     custom property used in the @media
     rules; allowing changes to be made
     in only one place: */
  --margin: 5px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.flex {
  /* using flex-layout: */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* allowing elements to wrap within
     the flex container: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background: #343436;
  /* using the --margin custom property
     to set the margins of the elements:*/
  margin: var(--margin);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <!-- what you were calling 'columns' were cells within
       a column; therefore I've adjusted both the text
       and the HTML itself; here the common class for
       all elements within the container is 'cell' for
       shared styles, and each cell can be targeted
       by its position; I used classes instead of id
       in case you have multiple flex-layouts within
       the same document with the same style: -->
  <div class="cell cell1">cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell cell2">cell 2</div>
  <div class="cell cell3">cell 3</div>
  <div class="cell cell4">cell 4</div>
  <div class="cell cell5">cell 5</div>
  <div class="cell cell6">cell 6</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bgmcr4tq/1/).

For CSS Grid, however:

```css
/* For various screen sizes we update the CSS
   custom properties: */
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
   :root {
    --columns: 6;
    --gridAreas:
        "one one one one one one"
        "two two two three three three"
        "four four five five six six";
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   :root {
    --columns: 2;
    --gridAreas:
        "one one"
        "two three"
        "four five"
        "six six";
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
   :root {
    --columns: 1;
    --gridAreas:
        "one"
        "two"
        "three"
        "four"
        "five"
        "six";
  }
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.grid {
  /* using CSS grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  /* defining the number of columns in the grid,
     as defined in the relevant @media rule: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
  /* using the --gridAreas custom property to
     determine the grid template and its named
     areas: */
  grid-template-areas: var(--gridAreas);
}

.cell {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background: #343436;
}

/* defining the grid-area into which
   each element will be placed: */
.cell1 {
  grid-area: one;
}

.cell2 {
  grid-area: two;
}

.cell3 {
  grid-area: three;
}

.cell4 {
  grid-area: four;
}

.cell5 {
  grid-area: five;
}

.cell6 {
  grid-area: six;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell cell1">cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell cell2">cell 2</div>
  <div class="cell cell3">cell 3</div>
  <div class="cell cell4">cell 4</div>
  <div class="cell cell5">cell 5</div>
  <div class="cell cell6">cell 6</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).
- [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink).
- [`gap` (`grid-gap`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`var()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)," CSS Tricks.
- "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)," CSS Tricks.
- "[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)," MDN.
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)," MDN.

Comment: Thorough answer, but cell 6 should be 100% of the width (according to OPs image)

Comment: @disinfor: for me, in both the linked JS Fiddle and Stack Snippet it is full width once the results viewport is below 500px (the width is changed in the answer for convenience). Does it not work for you? And if not, do you mean the flex or grid part? Or both?

Comment: You're right!! I forgot you mentioned you changed it to `500px` and not the 800. It's all good!

Comment: @disinfor: that’s a relief! Thank you for taking the time to raise a possible problem, and for the earlier compliment.

Comment: No problem! I love answers like this on SO. Where not only do you give the markup, but also the resources to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Add `flex-basis` or `flex` to those column, here's the working code (make sure the viewport-width is greater than 800px):

```
// add these with along with corresponding markup in HTML.
  .col-12 {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    flex: 50%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    flex: 33.3%;
  }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bytprgwm/

or direct snippet:

```css
/* Grid */

.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .column {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .col-12 {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    flex: 50%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    flex: 33.3%;
  }

}
/* Style */

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #343436;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column col-12">
    Column 1 - 100% 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column col-6">
    Column 2 - 50%
  </div>
  <div class="column col-6">
    Column 3 - 50%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column col-4">
    Column 4 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column col-4">
    Column 5 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column col-4">
    Column 6 - 33.3%
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Check your code. It doesn't work how the OP wants it.

Comment: @disinfor did you try on the large (than 800px) screen, I saw it work pretty well.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh It's supposed to change to what the image looks like BELOW 800px.

Comment: @disinfor ok. But I wonder why he wants 1 column layout in a big device while multiple columns in a small device

Answer (score 2):

This would be my solution:

```css
.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .column {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
/* Style */

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #343436;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .special{
    min-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 1 - 100% 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 2 - 50%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 3 - 50%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Column 4 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 5 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column special">
    Column 6 - 33.3%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but you need to account for the margin.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `flex`, you'll need to add some classes and do some `calc()` on the `flex-basis` to account for your margins - along with using `nth-child` selectors.

Grid is a much better way to go, but here's a flex solution.

```css
/* Grid */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}


/* Style */

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #343436;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 799px) {
  .row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .row.two .column {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 6px);
  }
  .row.two .column:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: 6px;
  }
  .row.two .column:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 6px;
  }
  .row.three .column {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 6px);
  }
  .row.three .column:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: 6px;
  }
  .row.three .column:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 6px;
  }
  .row.three .column:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row one">
  <div class="column">
    Column 1 - 100%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row two">
  <div class="column">
    Column 2 - 50%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 3 - 50%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row three">
  <div class="column">
    Column 4 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 5 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Column 6 - 33.3%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**RESULT**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column1">
    Column 1 - 100% 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column column2">
    Column 2 - 50%
  </div>
  <div class="column column3">
    Column 3 - 50%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row last-row">
  <div class="column column4">
    Column 4 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column column5">
    Column 5 - 33.3%
  </div>
  <div class="column column6">
    Column 6 - 33.3%
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.column1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.column2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.column3 {
  flex: 1;
}

.last-row {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column4 {
  width: 33.3%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.column5 {
  width: 33.3%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.column6 {
  width: 33.3%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .last-row {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }    
}

/* Style */
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #343436;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**DEMO**

https://codepen.io/wilsonbalderrama/pen/eYmgyNV